# How to make Image and Text on Listview in Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am testing making a Tabbed Layout with Different Content each Tab. 
In this Tab i want make layout with Image and Text inside Listview. 
This is code i wrote so far but not working.

Layout_One.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kreuzell.projecttest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/menuText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout_One.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.List;

public class Layout_One extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, container, false);

        String[] menuText = {
                "Text 1",
                "Text 2",
                "Text 3"
        };

        Integer[] menuImage = {
                R.drawable.image_1,
                R.drawable.image_2,
                R.drawable.image_3
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuText);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuImage);

        ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity();
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                menuText,
                menuImage
        )

        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I am new of this, Anybody can help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use adapter for the list view and edit the layout of the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom layout(layout1) which has your image and text positioned as you want. Then make a custom list adapter(mAdapter), use layout1 inside your mAdapter and fill it with data.Then set mAdapter to the list.

Please have a look at these tutorials, they will help you to understand how all this custom lists work:

1. [Vogella List Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
2. [Journal Dev List Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)